# Create a CDROM Bootdisk to update BIOS

Tags: boot, bios, bootable-media, compact-disc, windows-98

So, I have a Tyan Opteron board with a very old BIOS version. I realize Opteron's aren't exactly common like Athlons, Phenoms, Intel CPUs, etc. but my question revolves around updating the BIOS, however I don't have a floppy drive and there's no option to boot off of a USB key.

Tyan has incomplete instructions on their website ([link](http://www.tyan.com/tech/how_to_flash.aspx)) on how to flash the BIOS via USB. So my second tactic has been to create a Windows 98 boot-able CDROM with the flash utilities on it. It's been years since I've made one but after going to sites like bootdisk.com and such I haven't had any success.

Can anyone tell me step-by-step how to make a boot-able Windows 98 CDROM? I can't believe I'm having such a hard time doing this but I've failed on four different attempts and I must be doing something wrong or I'm not accounting for something.

Comment: *Must* it be Windows 98? Or would some variant of DOS be acceptable?

Comment: Tyan recommends Windows 95/98 on the website, although I would *assume* DOS 6+ would be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your burning software for a "Make disk bootable" option.  Sometimes even with all the correct files written to the disk, unless you tell the software to make the disk bootable, it will not work.

Comment: You know, I didn't think about this at all while burning the discs. I'll have to try it out and get back to you. If this is all it takes, then great!

Comment: Success. Apparently I forgot to tell the burner software to make the disc boot-able. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.